# Awk pattern search with variables

Tags: bash, variables, awk, pattern-matching

Ok so i can get a variable to pass into awk but when there is a space in variable it will not search anything so here is some code

```
 new="bob"
 searc=`awk '/#'$new':/,/---/ {print $0}'` file.txt
 echo "$searc"
```

should display something like this

```
  #bob:
   happy
   fun
   love
   sun
  ------
```

so the first example ^ works perfectly however Luke Jackson is never found now the reason for the name being stored in a variable is because it suppose to be dynamic so it can change. Now am i missing something simple here or i just cant do it this way?

```
 new="Luke Jackson"
 searc=`awk '/#'$new':/,/---/ {print $0}'` file.txt
 echo "$searc"

  #Luke Jackson:
   sad
   fun
   evil
   moon
  ------
```

Comment: Use double quotes: ```searc=`awk '/#'"$new"':/,/---/ {print $0}'` file.txt```

Comment: @anubhava it was typo out of habit with variables meant to be double quotes correct the text

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well that was exactly what i was missing i can't believe i didnt see that thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

if you rewrite your script slightly there won't be any issues

```
$ awk -v name='Luke Jackson' '$0~"#"name":"{f=1} f && /----/{f=0} f' file

  #Luke Jackson:
   sad
   fun
   evil
   moon
```

note also that perhaps instead of pattern matching you need exact match, in that case use `==`

Answer (score 0):

Simple sed can also solve this:

```
new='Luke Jackson'
sed -n "/#$new:/,/---/p" file

#Luke Jackson:
sad
fun
evil
moon
------
```

Comment: `-n` suppresses normal output and `/p` prints only the selected part from the file.

Comment: brilliant I never knew I could do this with sed! thanks!